# INSERT result for SELECT FROM join'ed tables just modified

Tags: postgresql, cte

I have the task to insert data into couple tables and return data from their intersection in one query. The tables are linked through specific fields (`solditems` refers to `products` and `invoices`, `invoices` refers to `customers` etc). The trick here is that `id` in `invoices` is set automatically on row insert. The following query returns an empty result, unless I remove `JOIN` on `invoices`. If the `SELECT` is done in a separate query everything is OK. What's wrong?

```
WITH newid AS (
INSERT INTO invoices (customer,idate)
    VALUES (777,(SELECT now()::date))
    RETURNING id
),
sold AS (
INSERT INTO solditems (invoiceid,prod,qty)
    VALUES ((SELECT id FROM newid), 888, 1),
           ((SELECT id FROM newid), 999, 2)
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM sold AS s
   JOIN products AS p ON p.id=s.prod
   JOIN invoices AS i ON i.id=s.invoiceid;
```

Comment: *What's wrong?* INSERT in WITH performs "I will insert a row with returned ID" - but the row is not inserted yet. And you do not see it while selecting from `invoices` table. Return all columns in `newid` instead of `id` column only, and join this CTE instead of `invoices` table.

Comment: Investigate https://dbfiddle.uk/laYcevlv If you need the whole table, not only inserted row then use `(table UNION ALL cte)`.

Comment: @Akina Thank you very much! Now it is clear to me and the modified query works as expected. If you post this as the answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina) explained, all CTEs and the outer `SELECT` of the same command see the same snapshot of the table, so the new row is not visible to the `SELECT`, yet. See:

- [Why can't rows inserted in a CTE be updated in the same statement?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151199/why-cant-rows-inserted-in-a-cte-be-updated-in-the-same-statement/151217#151217)
- [Can I select data inserted in the same uncommited transaction?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98576/can-i-select-data-inserted-in-the-same-uncommited-transaction/98580#98580)

Return all you need in the `RETURNING` clause:

```
WITH ins_invo AS (
   INSERT INTO invoices (customer, idate)
   SELECT 777, CURRENT_DATE  -- !
   RETURNING *  --!
   )
, ins_sold AS (
   INSERT INTO solditems (invoiceid, prod, qty)
   SELECT i.id, v.p, v.q  -- !
   FROM   ins_invo i
   CROSS  JOIN (
      VALUES (888, 1)
           , (999, 2)
      ) v(p, q)
   RETURNING *
   )
SELECT *
FROM   ins_sold      s
JOIN   ins_invo      i ON i.id = s.invoiceid
LEFT   JOIN products p ON p.id = s.prod  --!
;
```

You also join to products to retrieve (assumingly one) pre-existing row from table `products`. Use a `LEFT JOIN` there, or you get nothing back if there is no matching row in `products`. Unless referential integrity is enforced with an FK constraints from `sold.prod` → `products.id`, then you'd get an exception for the missing `products.id`, and this point is moot. (Doesn't hurt in any case, though.)

Also simplified repeated `SELECT`, where you only need one.